How can I deal with a map <string, string> column in Redshift
I have a table in amazone athena with the column datatypevmap<string,string>.  The column is called properties and it looks like this (example):
{"isAutomaticRemindersEnabled":"False","isDuplicated":"False","isParticipantsHidden":"False", "browser":"Chrome","description":"meeting is created successfully","timezone":"Europe/Madrid","isDeadlineEnabled":"False","numberOfOptions":"75","organizationFormActionType":"edit","isDescriptionAdded":"False","planType":"free","browserVersion":"99.0.4844.51","country":"ES","deviceCategory":"desktop","operatingSystem":"Windows NT 10.0","language":"es","isInTrial":"False","meetingType":"group","category":"meeting","userId":"lh9qjecjqri3fccn3tnfomw9l77nbq26","slotDurationInMinutes":"120","isLoggedIn":"True","isAllDayChosen":"False"}.

From here, I want to get meetingType only. When i query from Athena it is easy to do. But I want to run the query in Redshift. This table will be part of staging layer in dbt, as it is, without any change. And from there on, transformations will be applied, including the use of meetingType only. Any suggestion how to deal with it? Nothing is working so far.
I tried to convert to text, and use regex, but regex function were not recognize from redshift.

Redshift has a full set of regexp functions - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html
However, the better way to do this is to use Redshift's json parsing functions.  JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT() can extract the key you are looking for from your valid json text.
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_col, 'meetingType')

should do the trick.
Also, you could convert this data into a super data type and parse it directly w/o a json function but this is overkill for the use case you are describing.

thank you for your answer, but i have already tried json parsing function, but somehow it does not work, I will try the super data type, let's see if it will make sense

Can you post the error you get?  Also the data you posted has a trailing '.' which I thought was just a typo in the question.  If this is really in your data then this isn't valid json and won't parse.  You'll need to remove this before parsing the text as json.

converting to super datatype made the trick, thank you for the suggestion: ,cast(properties as super) as properties
